# iMac Doesn't see Ethernet Cable

Tags: macos, imac, ethernet

I have a strange problem with my iMac (mid. 2011 21,5) -  I can't connect to the network using Ethernet because OS X tells me that it's disconnected when it's plugged in. Sometimes it can see the connection, but  the Internet won't work.

Now, I also have this problem with Wi-Fi, it connects to a network but after random time Internet connection stops working. All other computers and phones are working with Ethernet and Wi-Fi; only the iMac isn't.

I tried to do all tests and resets but nothing, today I formatted it returning from Yosemite to Snow Leopard but the problem is still there. Any solution?

[image: network]

Comment: If the problem persists on Snow Leopard it may be a hardware problem.

Comment: I hope no, but I think so, because now after formatting OS X can't connect through Ethernet anyway.

Comment: I also have Imac mid 2011. I experience the exact same frustrating issues. I am running Yosemite as well however just to point out the issue for me began before the Yosemite upgrade. I have just chosen to ignore it and make do. I had never used the ehternet port until I tried to hardwire it well before I upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: Sure sounds like hardware failure if Ethernet shows not connected. The driver has nothing to do with OS X versions and the connection happens when power is applied way before the OS even starts.

Answer (score 2):

Just for grins and giggles...

Did you verify that your cable and network port are good?

First thing to try is moving your connection from whatever port on the switch it is on to another.  Sometimes a port on the switch just may be bad.

You will also want to verify the cable.  If you have access to another computer or a laptop, remove the patch cable from your iMac and plug it into the laptop.  If the problem persists, then you will need to solve that issue before doing more diagnostics on your iMac.

Once you have verified that the connection from the switch to your iMac is good, then I would proceed with diagnosing the hardware, then the software on the iMac.

Comment: I agree. The Ethernet connection happens with the power being applied. Doesn't matter if you run Bootcamp and Windows, Linux, or any version of OS X. No connection is a hardware or cabling or switch issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Network Diagnostics app located in the `/System/Library/CoreServices.`

Then Run it to check your Ethernet settings, and/or recommend solutions.

[image: network]

To be able to run the test, you need to have the Ethernet connection set up in your Network-Location screen. If it is not there set it up using the (+). Newer mind me calling it Comcast, you can choose the name for the Location.

[image: ethernet]

Then also try the different choice:

[image: network]

Also disable the WiFi then try the ethernet.

Comment: I've tried the Network Diagnostics but it tells that it can't resolve the problem, maybe because it can't find any network through Ethernet connection.

Comment: OK, show us your syst pref Network - where it shows all your connections set up (as a screen shot) please

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here my connection configuration: http://cdn.img42.com/909a81de97b71f859b2f4da027edf4f4.jpeg

Comment: Did you try different protocols (Change the Configura IPv4 ...... to other protocols beside DHCP).  In my case it is "PPP", but you can try the any other.

Comment: I tried but no success, I think that the network card is damaged, it's possible repair it or is integrated with the rest (in iMac)?

Comment: You can do a test before spending money on a new card and performing the surgery. You would need a second mac or pc and a "Crossover Ethernet cable". That would allow you to see if you can transfer files and if the Ethernet card is working. The cost is minimal and there is no surgical approach. You can get it in many places at about $10. http://www.walmart.com/ip/Belkin-Cat6-Crossover-Cable/38348660

Answer (score -1):

in Yosemite you can choose Network Diagnostics by clicking the WiFi icon in the menubar *while holding the Alt(option) key*. It is the third entry.
In Snow Leopard the Network Diagnostics is in the Utilities folder as far as I remember.
Lex

Comment: I've tried Network Diagnostics in Yosemite and in Snow Leopard (10.6.8) but it can't resolve the problem because it can't find the Ethernet connection, for the WiFi when works it tell that all is fine (and it's true) when not works it tell to restart router.

Answer (score -3):

Reinstalling OS X fixed the problem for me (using El Capitan).